# Regex: Select all from row except tags

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this kind of rows.

```
<li><a href="love-and-attitude.html" title="Love and Attitude">Love and Attitude (24)</a></li>
<li><a href="paint-and-gain.html" title="Paint And Gain">Paint And Gain (15)</a></li>
<li><a href="mother-and-father.html" title="Mother And Father">Mother And Father (19)</a></li>
```

I want to select with regex only the text between title tag and close  tag. So, after using regex, I should have. The desire output:

> Love and Attitude (24)
>
> Paint And Gain (15)
>
> Mother And Father (19)

Comment: You can get a hint in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592033/regex-match-text-between-tags/11592042

Comment: it's not quite the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caution:** this will not work if you have `>` in any attribute of `<a>` tag or `<` in the text you want to extract. In that case you have to use a parser instead.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*<li><a[^>]+>([^<]+).+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  <li><a    # literally
  [^>]+     # 1 or more any character that is not >
  >         # literally >
  (         # start group 1
    [^<]+   # 1 or more any character that is not <
  )         # end group 1
  .+        # 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (i.e. the text you want)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Love and Attitude (24)
Paint And Gain (15)
Mother And Father (19)
```